# Save Locations & Photos in #dotnet 7

Tags: .net, azure, blob

I have mobile project (Maui) and an API.

I have to save many location points with photos throught this API (or other, will speak about).
To begin, I'm made this, in the client side:

```
    var bigObjectCloned = BigObject.Clone();
    bigObjectCloned.Points.Clear();
    bigObjectCloned.Photos.Clear();
    var simpleObjectFromAPI = await saveJustAsync(bigObjectCloned);

    simpleObjectFromAPI.Points = BigObject.Points;
    await savePointsAsync(bigObjectFromAPI);

    simpleObjectFromAPI.Points.Clear();
    simpleObjectFromAPI.Photos = BigObject.Pictures;
    await saveImagesAsync(simpleObjectFromAPI);
```

For the server side, I used EF 7 + Azure Blob Storage for photos.

Many problems:

1. Those POST actions can be long. If I have 100*points & 50*photos it'll be hell long.
2. I cannot get status of the object saving.
3. It is blocking my UI client side.

My questions:

- How can I save this large object to avoid blocking UI ?
- How can I ask for the status ?
- How can I make a queue when many people are saving ?

Thanks for your time & expertize ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You are in a mobile application, you shouldn't block the UI.

With many and large uploads.. You got it all (ironical)!

You can use a "background" task in each platform:

Get inspired by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/ios-backgrounding-with-tasks for iOS and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services documentation for Android for the mobile implementation.

For the upload, you can use the official SDKs from Azure:

```
// Create a local file in the ./data/ directory for uploading and downloading
string localPath = "data";
Directory.CreateDirectory(localPath);
string fileName = "quickstart" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".txt";
string localFilePath = Path.Combine(localPath, fileName);

// Write text to the file
await File.WriteAllTextAsync(localFilePath, "Hello, World!");

// Get a reference to a blob
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);

Console.WriteLine("Uploading to Blob storage as blob:\n\t {0}\n", blobClient.Uri);

// Upload data from the local file
await blobClient.UploadAsync(localFilePath, true);
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet?tabs=visual-studio%2Cmanaged-identity%2Croles-azure-portal%2Csign-in-azure-cli%2Cidentity-visual-studio#upload-a-blob-to-a-container

Comment: I'm already in a background service in my Maui mobile app.
I don't want my mobile app knows about Azure.